# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02180: invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE

Tags: oracle, javafx

I am trying to create a new tablespace ( i work with javafx), I write my command in the controller like this :

my code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package projetoracle;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class FXMLcreate_permanentController implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private TextField file;

    @FXML
    private TextField size;

    @FXML
    private Button valider;

    @FXML
    private Button quitter;

    @FXML
    private TextField nom;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Label> accessible;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Label> typefile;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Label> segment;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Label> extension;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Label> journalisation;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Label> unite;

    @FXML
    private TextField extent;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Label> size3;

    @FXML
    void handleButtonActionquitter(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void handleButtonActionvalider(ActionEvent event) {


         String createQuery;
          String co = "'";
        createQuery ="CREATE"+ " " +typefichier()+ " " +"TABLESPACE"+ " " +nom.getText().toString()+"DATAFILE"+ " "+ co +file.getText().toString()+ ".dbf"+ co + " "+"SIZE" +size.getText().toString()+ " " +tailleall()+ " " +allocate()+ " " +auto()+ " " +journalisation()+ " " +online();


        try{

            DBUtil.dbExecuteUpdate(createQuery);
            System.out.println("Succées d'ajout");     
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("erreur!");
        }

    }
         public String typefichier()
        {
            if (typefile.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().toString().equals("Smallfile"))
                return "SMALLFILE";
            else
                return "BIGFILE";
        }

         public String online()
        {
            if (accessible.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().toString().equals("Online"))
                return "ONLINE";
            else
                return "OFFLINE";
        }

         public String allocate()
        {
            if (extension.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().toString().equals("Autoallocate"))
                return "EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE";
            else
                return "EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE " + extent.getText() +taillealle();
        }

        public String tailleall()
        {
            if (unite.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().toString().equals("Ko"))

                return "K";
            else if (unite.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().toString().equals("Mo"))

                return "M";
            else
                return "G";
        }



          private String journalisation()
        {
            if (journalisation.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().toString().equals("logging"))
                return "LOGGING";
            else
                return "NOLOGGING";
        }
           private String auto()
        {
            if (segment.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().toString().equals("Auto"))
                return "SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO";
            else
                return "SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT MANUAL";
        }

     String taillealle(){
          if (size3.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().toString().equals("Ko"))
                return "K";
            else if (size3.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().toString().equals("Ko"))
                return "M";
            else
                return "G";

     }







    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
     unite.getItems().add(new Label("Ko"));
     unite.getItems().add(new Label("Mo"));
     unite.getItems().add(new Label("Go"));

     accessible.getItems().add(new Label("Online"));
     accessible.getItems().add(new Label("Offline"));

     typefile.getItems().add(new Label("Smallfile"));
     typefile.getItems().add(new Label("Bigfile"));

     segment.getItems().add(new Label("Auto"));
     segment.getItems().add(new Label("Manual"));

     extension.getItems().add(new Label("Autoallocate"));
     extension.getItems().add(new Label("Uniform"));

     journalisation.getItems().add(new Label("No logging"));
    journalisation.getItems().add(new Label("logging"));



     size3.getItems().add(new Label("Ko"));
     size3.getItems().add(new Label("Mo"));
     size3.getItems().add(new Label("Go"));

}

}
```

i think it's correct but when i run i have this problem

```
Problem occurred at executeUpdate operation : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02180: invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE
```

What am I doing wrongly? 
any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Print out the statement before you execute it. You're missing at least two spaces between terms - before DATAFILE and after SIZE, and possibly in the other terms you're concatenating in after that as well.

Comment: it works now thank you :) @AlexPoole